# Problems with DataTable.Dispose()

Tags: c#

Problems with DataTable.Dispose()

Hello.

I have the problem with the following code, it causes problems in the memory. 
The problem is that don't know as giving the turn to this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using Microsoft.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace Mirf
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 SqlConnection Lig = new SqlConnection();
        DataTable DataTab = new DataTable();


            string str_ligacao_bd = "Data Source=.\\SQL2005;Database=Bd;Integrated Security=SSPI";

            Lig = new SqlConnection(str_ligacao_bd);
            Lig.Open();

            //Efectua a intrução á tabela seleccionada base de dados
            SqlCommand cmd = Lig.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tab";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "tab");
            DataTab = ds.Tables["tab"];


            cmd.Dispose();
            da.Dispose();
            ds.Dispose();
            Lig.Close();


            foreach (DataColumn  d in DataTab.Columns)
            {
                string linha = d.ColumnName;
                if (linha != "Tid")
                {
                    linha = "[" + linha + "]=1";
                    int sum = (int)(DataTab.Compute("COUNT(TID)",linha));
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

he code is.

Which the best way to do to count the values of 1 in the several columns.
      In some situations it will be necessary to combine two or more columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve here, but it looks like you really should be using SQL to get your answer directly rather than reading the entire table into local memory and then computing things locally.

Comment: Hello the problem is the you DataTable is reading from text file not direct the SqlServer.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your table?. By getting all the data from SQL and computing things in .NET you consume too much memory. Use the database, compute your data in SQL and just fetch the result in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you said in another comment that the data is in a text file (although your code suggests it is in an SQL Server database) I would suggest using Linq to Entities.

Here's some links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386992.aspx

http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/adoef_vs_linqsql.htm

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2008/03/selecting-custom-objects-from-linq.html

You would have to write code to serialise and deserialise the "rows" of data you want to build queries against to in-memory C# objects.